# Analysis of Algorithms: Solving Recursion equations-$T(n)=3T(n-2)+9$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I need your help with solving this recursion equation: $T(n)=3T(n-2)+9$
with the initial condition: $T(1)=T(2)=1.$

I need to find $T(n),$ the complexity of the algorithm which works that way.

I tried to do that with induction.

Edit: The answer should depend on $n.$

Thank you.

Comment: Note that there is no communication between the odd and even $n$, so you can make it $T(m)=3T(m-1)+9$ with $T(1)=1$.

Comment: I have to ask, is this homework?

Comment: No, it is not..

Comment: I deteted my answer, because it was wrong. @user6312:Thanks! You are right, my answer was for a different recursion, as you wrote $U(n)=3U(n-1)+9U(n-2)$.

Comment: Nir, @user6312: I decided to undelete and edit my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Undeleted and edited. This idea is an expansion of Ross Millikan's comment. If there's any error the fault is mine.*

The first few terms are

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
T(1) &=&T(2)=U(1)=1 \\
T(3) &=&T(4)=U(2)=12 \\
T(5) &=&T(6)=U(3)=45 \\
&&\cdots 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Generalizing, we have

$$T(2n-1)=T(2n)=U(n),\qquad n\ge 1.\qquad (1)$$

Since

$$T(2n-1)=3T(2n-3)+9=3T(2n-2)+9,$$

we obtain

$$U(1)=1,\qquad U(n)=3U(n-1)+9,\qquad n\ge 2.\qquad (2)$$

We will apply the rudiments of the theory of recurrences (or difference equations, see e.g. *[An introduction to difference equations](http://books.google.pt/books?id=MB3WFXoLDMQC&pg=PR13&dq=difference%20equations%20springer&hl=pt-PT&ei=IdEWTs_9G8enhAfG6OTMBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=difference%20equations%20springer&f=false)* by Saber Elaydi). This is an [*nonhomogeneous* recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations), consequently we have to find a *particular solution* of the recurrence and solve the [*homogeneous* recurrence, which is linear and has constant coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). Hence, the explicit solution is of the form

$$U(1)=1,\qquad U(n)=AX^{n}+C,\qquad (3)$$

where $X$ is the root of the [*characteristic equation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) $X-3=0$ associated to the *homogeneous* equation $U(n)-3U(n-1)=0$ and $C$ is  a particular solution (a constant, in this case) of $U(n)=3U(n-1)+9$. From $(2)$, we must have $C=3C+9$, i.e. $C=-9/2$. So $U(n)=3^{n}A-9/2$.

From the initial conditions $U(1)=1$, we get $1=3A-9/2$, and $A=11/6$. Thus the solution of $(2)$ is

$$U(n)=\frac{11}{6}3^{n}-\frac{9}{2},\qquad n\ge 1.\qquad (4)$$

Thus the solution of the given recurrence $T(n)=3T(n-2)+9$ is

$$T(2n-1)=T(2n)=U(n)=\frac{11}{6}3^{n}-\frac{9}{2},\qquad n\ge 1.\qquad (5)$$

Comment: @user6312: I undeleted and edited the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: First consider $G(n) = T(n) + \frac{9}{2}$

Comment: Can you please extend your hint? I don't see how I can consider it.

Comment: @Nir: Try to get a recurrence which $G(n)$ satisfies.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: @Nir: If $T(n) = 3 T(n-2) + 9$ and $G(n) = T(n) + 9/2$ then can you try an write $G(n)$ in terms of $G(n-2)$?

Comment: Sure I can, it's simply $G(n)=3G(n-2)$.

Comment: @Nir: So $G(n) = 3 G(n-2) = 9 G(n-4) = 27G(n-6) = \dots$, can you do something with that?

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks. How did you of this $G(n)$ at the beginning?

Comment: @Nir: The idea is to try to get rid of the constant. So you offset $T(n)$. So if $G(n) = T(n) - c$, we want $c$ so that $G(n) = 3G(n-2)$. Put that in, and see if we can solve for $c$ (also see the latter half of Brian's answer).

Answer (score 4):

Induction is a way to prove things; it's not generally helpful in solving computational problems, except perhaps in proving that a guessed solution is correct.

Note that the values of $T(n)$ for odd $n$ are completely independent of the values for even $n$, so you can look at it as essentially two separate instances of the recursion $f(n+1) = 3f(n) + 9$ with initial condition $f(1) = 1$. There are lots of ways to solve that recurrence. One is to 'unwind' it, which is a bit like doing an induction: $f(n) = 3f(n-1)+9 = 3(3f(n-2)+9)+9$ = $3^2f(n-2)+3$ and so on. If you continue in this fashion, you'll find that after $k$ steps you have $f(n)$ = $3^kf(n-k) + 9 \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}3^i$; in particular, when $k=n-1$ you have $f(n) = 3^{n-1}f(1)+9\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}3^i$ = $3^{n-1} + 9 \cdot \frac{3^{n-1}-1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(11 \cdot 3^{n-1} - 9\right)$.

Now $T(2n) = f(n) = \frac{1}{2}\left(11 \cdot 3^{n-1} - 9\right)$, and $T(2n-1) = f(n) = \frac{1}{2}\left(11 \cdot 3^{n-1} - 9\right)$.

A neater way to solve the $f$ recurrence is to let $g(n) = f(n) - d$ for some constant $d$ yet to be determined. Then $f(n) = g(n) + d$, so the recurrence can be written $g(n+1)+d$ = $3 \left(g(n)+d \right) + 9$ = $3g(n) + 3d + 9$, or $g(n+1)=3g(n) + 2d + 9$. Setting $d=-9/2$ makes this $g(n+1)=3g(n)$ with initial condition $g(1)=f(1)+9/2=11/2$. This is simple exponential growth: $g(n) = 3^{n-1}g(1)= \frac{11}{2} \cdot 3^{n-1}$. Hence $f(n) = g(n)-9/2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(11 \cdot 3^{n-1} - 9\right)$, of course giving the same solution for the original problem.